# Mixed random variable (Exponential distribution mixed with binomial distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ be an exponential distribution of parameter $1$.

And let $Y$ be the binomial distribution of parameter $n$ and $p=1/2$.

We define $Z=\frac{X}{Y+1}$. I'm trying to find the distribution  of $Z$.

This is what I did :

Let $t>0$ we have $F(Z<t)=F(X<t(Y+1))=\int_{0}^{t(Y+1)}exp(-x)dx=1-exp(-t(Y+1))$

and for $t<0$ we have $F(Z<t)=0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to sum over all possible values of Y.

Let's condition over $Y$. We get:

$$P(Z<t) = \sum\limits_k P(Z<t|Y=k) P(Y=k)$$

So your net probability will become (using the fact that $Y$ is binomial):

$$P(Z<t) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n (1-e^{-t(k+1)}) {n \choose k} p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

$$ = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}- e^{-t}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (e^{-t}p)^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$
$$ = 1-e^{-t}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} (e^{-t}p)^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Comment: Why did we sum over all possible values of $Y$, instead of sum from $k=0$ to for example $k=j$ with $j<n$ ?

Comment: @Pandey can you please just write where exactly the first line come from ?

Comment: My counter question to that would be, why would we *not* sum over all possible values of $Y$? There is a probability that this value of $Y$ will be realized (whatever it might be) and conditional on that value of $Y$, there will be a certain probability $Z<t$.

Comment: yes makes sens, thank you

Comment: If this addressed your query, don't forget to mark as accepted answer :)